# regular expression for getting update string is not getting

Tags: php, regex

i have a file which contains a lot of update query and some other data i need to get the update query from that file using regular expression

my file contains :

> 2012-03-14 23:29:24 WebModule[]update PAYOUT_HDR set C_ELNO='665656'
>   where N_ID='68' and D_TO=to_date('24/02/2012','dd/MM/yyyy') 2012-03-14
>   23:57:57 WebModule[]update address_dtl set C_FIRM_NAME='MISS',
>   c_fname='gggg', c_lname='testtt.G',c_addr1='test
>   ',c_addr2='test',c_addr3='test,
>   testtt',c_district='31001',c_state='27',c_zip_code='444',c_tele_no='555555',c_mobile='444444',c_email='4444@44.com' where n_id=522 and c_type='666'

i tried

```
preg_match_all("/\update (.*)\)/i", $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

but its not working. Please help me to fix this issue

```
preg_match_all("/update (.*\))/i", $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

ok if the query ends with a ) but  i need all update queries

Comment: Please write more than one example from log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your regex. The below works with your sample input.

```
preg_match_all("/update (.*\))/i", $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

That said, your current approach only matches queries that end with a ).

**Update**

This will get both update queries from you example string:

```
<?php

$contents = "2012-03-14 23:29:24 WebModule[]update PAYOUT_HDR set C_ELNO='665656' where N_ID='68' and D_TO=to_date('24/02/2012','dd/MM/yyyy') 2012-03-14 23:57:57 WebModule[]update address_dtl set C_FIRM_NAME='MISS', c_fname='gggg', c_lname='testtt.G',c_addr1='test
',c_addr2='test',c_addr3='test,
testtt',c_district='31001',c_state='27',c_zip_code='444',c_tele_no='555555',c_mobile='444444',c_email='4444@44.com' where n_id=522 and c_type='666'";

$parts = preg_split('/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/', $contents);
$updates = array();
foreach($parts as $part){
    if(!trim($part)){
        continue;
    }
    preg_match_all("/update.*/si", $part, $matches);
    if(count($matches)){
        $updates[] = $matches[0][0];
    }
}
print_r($updates);
```

Comment: if the query ending with a ) its ok.. can u please tell if its ending with any thing

Comment: If the queries are separated by "any thing" then it is impossible so split them, because it is impossible to know if a new query has started. Are there no line breaks in the log?

Comment: if all are end with date eg : 2012-03-22  what are the chenges

Comment: A regular expression like `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` would match the date. You could either incorporate that into the above or use preg_split to explode the string on that pattern. But you could potentially also have such dates in your queries, so I am not sure it is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

If that is just a string in your file then you can read that file and get all the data into a variable and after that you can split that string like:-

```
$array = explode(" WebModule[]",$string);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

$string is the variable that keeps the entire string.

Comment: need regular expression because WebModule[] not always be there

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape "u" in update - it assumes you are calling for perl mode (PCRE)

```
/update (.*)\)/i
```

Comment: but it shows <span > etc.. in the output while i print $matches

Comment: otherwise it shows the error Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 1 in D:\w